# What are differences between Project Manager, Project Expeditor and Project Coordinator?

Tags: roles, organizational-structure

What are differences between these positions in matrix organization structure?

There is no "Project Expeditor" in [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/definition-and-distinctions-between-project-x-program-x-portfolio-x-product-mana) and it is not related with matrix organization structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Definition and distinctions between Project x Program x Portfolio x Product Managers](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/definition-and-distinctions-between-project-x-program-x-portfolio-x-product-mana)

Comment: Does this definitions help: http://www.e-wbs.com/sample-page/basics-white-belt-training/what-is-project-management/project-managers-vs-project-coordinators-vs-project-expediter/
If not, could you expand the aspect regarding the matrix organisation more (e.g. motivation of the question)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PMBoK Guide (Fifth edition) it is written following:

> Matrix organizations can be classified as weak, balanced, or strong
>   depending on the relative level of power and influence between
>   functional and project managers. Weak matrix organizations maintain
>   many of the characteristics of a functional organization, and the *role
>   of the project manager is more of a coordinator or expediter*.
>
> A **project expediter** works as staff assistant and communications
>   coordinator. The expediter cannot personally make or enforce
>   decisions.
>
> **Project coordinators** have power to make some decisions,
>   have some authority, and report to a higher-level manager. Strong
>   matrix organizations have many of the characteristics of the
>   projectized organization, and have full-time project managers with
>   considerable authority and full-time project administrative staff.
>
> While the balanced matrix organization recognizes the need for a
>   project manager, it does not provide the project manager with the full
>   authority over the project and project funding.

P.S. The [Tobias's link](http://www.e-wbs.com/sample-page/basics-white-belt-training/what-is-project-management/project-managers-vs-project-coordinators-vs-project-expediter/) also has a good explanation of these terms.

Answer (score 2):

An expeditor acts primary as a staff assistant and communications coordinator and has no decision-making capability. A coordinator has some authority and some power to make decisions and reports to a higher level manager. Therefore the correct answer appears to be coordinator.